# Class 'ZipArchive' not found in opencart

Tags: opencart, php-ziparchive

I am getting an error "Class 'ZipArchive' not found in opencart" whenever i am trying to export from server.
It works fine from loacl system
what is the exact problem can anyone tell me ?

In server: php version 5.5.32

In local: php version 5.5.9

Comment: Do you have zip.so extension enabled in your server?

Comment: In my local system if i print phpinfo(); It shows that zip is enable.
But in server it is not showing, means it is not enable.
How to enable zip.so in server?

Answer (score 1):

**STEP 1:**

Go to Cpanel - PHP Pear Packages - Find PHP Extension - Search for zip.
Install the zip extension found.

**STEP 2:**

Go to Cpanel - Select PHP Version - Tick the zip Option - Save.

Now try to upload the .ocmod.zip file. Should work now.
Worked for me.

Comment: You're the best! This solution worked for me

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me too this morning.  From Cpanel I went to Select PHP version, and then checked the zip extension before I installed Opencart 3.02.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the extension zip.so extension, by adding the following line of code to your server php.ini file:

```
extension=zip.so
```

Comment: Still getting this error "Fatal error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found in /home/project/public_html/system/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php on line 232"

Answer (score 0):

This problem is raised due to some server configuration.

If you are on linux server you need to add zip archive module in php version.

```
cpanel -> Select PHP version -> check zip module in this page
```